# How to Efficient way comma separator use

Tags: c#, string

I work on C#. I have an array. To separate the array items I need to use comma. I did it but I think it's not efficient. How to do that, without an if condition? Please don't use replace method. My syntax is below.

```
string container = "";
string[] s = "Hellow world how are you".Split(' ');
foreach (string item in s)
{
    if (container == "")
    {
        container += item;
    }
    else
    {
        container += "," + item;
    }
}
```

I must need to continue the loop. I just want below type solution.

```
string container = "";
string[] s = "Hellow world how are you".Split(' ');
foreach (string item in s)
{
    container += "," + item;
}
```

Thanks in advance. If have any queries please ask.

Answer (score 13):

Using `String.Join` to join an array with comma separators.

```
string[] s = "Hello world how are you".Split(' ');
string container = String.Join(",", s);
```

Also, if you like getting help on this site, I recommend you start accepting a few answers.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is not the `if` statement. Your problem is that it is generally poor form and bad practice to perform string concatenation and other manipulations in a loop. The `string` class is immutable, changes are creating new strings, allocation new memory, etc. As a result, this practice is slow and inefficient, much more than your `if` statement will be. The more iterations of your loop, the more you'll notice the inefficiency.

You should familiarize yourself with the `StringBuilder` class, which allows you to perform efficient manipulations of a `string` without repeatedly allocating new objects. It is particularly useful in loops like yours above.

An example of using a `StringBuilder` is like the following

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
foreach (string item in array)
{
    if (builder.Length != 0) builder.Append(",");
    builder.Append(item);
}

string finalOutput = builder.ToString();
```

With that said, `string.Join` is also a powerful tool for the type of concatenation you are performing.

Answer (score 0):

`string.split` **starts with a string** and **ends with an array of strings** and
is very fast . It uses unsafe code to determine the indexes of the separators. Then it allocates the array of the correct size and then cuts up the original string by allocating a bunch of other strings.

`string.join` **starts with an array of strings** and **ends with a string** and  is also very fast and uses unsafe code. It creates a buffer and adds to the buffer each item in the string growing the string as it goes.

But since you want to **Start with a string** and **end with a string** your best bet is to use a method that uses unsafe code to change the ' ' with ','.

```
        string s1 = "Hellow world how are you";
        fixed (char* p = s1)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < s1.Length; i++)
            {
                if (p[i] == ' ')
                {
                    p[i] = ',';
                }
            }

        }
```

**This is a really bad idea**

- It only works because the source and target are the same length
- It requires unsafe code
- Since I'm mutating the string directly all references to the string get updated
- There's probably a bunch of checks that I'm missing
- Its only marginally faster then `string.replace`

Just use `String.Replace` if you really need it to be very fast and its very safe